# Errors with Unsorted List?

Tags: c++

So I have a homework assignment due tonight and I'm trying to compile it to test but I'm running into a bunch of errors and some of them seem to make zero sense? The errors mention things like: "syntax error before '::'" and the like, but I have never encountered errors like these and have 0 idea on how to fix them.

UnsortedClass.cpp

```
#include "UnsortedClass.h"

void UnsortedType::UnsortedType()
{
  length = 0;
}
bool UnsortedType::IsFull() const
{
  return (length == MAX_ITEMS);
}
int UnsortedType::GetLength() const
{
  return length;
}

NBA UnsortedType::GetItem(NBA customPlayer, bool& found) 
{
  bool moreToSearch;
  int location = 0;
  found = false;

  moreToSearch = (location < length);

  while (moreToSearch && !found) 
  {
    switch (customPlayer.ComparedTo(info[location]))
    {
      case LESS    : 
      case GREATER : location++;
                     moreToSearch = (location < length);
                     break;
      case EQUAL   : found = true;
                     item = info[location];
                     break;
    }
  }
  return customPlayer;
}
void UnsortedType::MakeEmpty()
{
  length = 0;
}
void UnsortedType::PutItem(NBA customPlayer)
{
  info[length] = customPlayer;
  length++;
}
void UnsortedType::DeleteItem(NBA customPlayer)
{
  int location = 0;

  while (customPlayer.ComparedTo(info[location]) != EQUAL)
    location++;

  info[location] = info[length - 1];
  length--;
}
void UnsortedType::ResetList()
{
  currentPos = -1;
}
NBA UnsortedType::GetNextItem()
{
  currentPos++;
  return info[currentPos];
}
```

UnsortedClass.h

```
#include "NBA.h"
class UnsortedClass  //declares a class data type
{
public: 
    // 8 public member functions
    void UnsortedType ( );
    bool IsFull () const; //checks if list is full
    int GetLength () const ; // returns length of list
    NBA GetItem (NBA customPlayer, bool& found); //gets item specified in parameters
    void PutItem (NBA customPlayer); //puts NBA player in list
    void DeleteItem (NBA customPlayer); //deletes NBA player from list
    void ResetList (); //resets list to 0
    NBA GetNextItem (); //gets next item after current list position
private:
    // 3 private data members
    int length; 
    NBA info[MAX_ITEMS]; 
    int currentPos;
};
```

NBA.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
enum RelationType  {LESS, GREATER, EQUAL};
class NBA {
    private:
        char firstInitial;
        string lastName;
        string team;
        char position;
    public:
        void set_first_initial(char playerFirstInitial);
        void set_last_name(string playerLastName);
        void set_team(string teamName);
        void set_position(char position);
        char get_first_initial();
        string get_last_name();
        string get_team();
        char get_position();
};
```

The errors I've been receiving are as follows (in picture format as I can't paste the lines without Stackoverflow interpreting it as code)

[image: Error List]

Comment: `UnsortedClass` or `UnsortedType` is the name of the class?, compile using a new version of compiler G++ 4.9.1 or Clang 3.5, the diagnostic are improved much.

Comment: Also, you should not put a `using namespace` in a header (and I would suggest avoiding it altogether for `std`).

Comment: @crashmstr /I/ know that, but our teacher insists so...rather than get a diminished grade, I'm going to just follow what she says =\

Comment: @NetVipeC you know...I can't believe I didn't notice that after looking at this for a good 2 hours.  Thank you ~.~

Comment: @TaiM.  I can - I've done similar before:(

Answer (score 1):

Constructors don't have a return type specified. Change

```
void UnsortedType::UnsortedType()
```

to

```
UnsortedType::UnsortedType()
```

Also the class name in its header declaration is wrong; everywhere else says `UnsortedType` but this says:

```
class UnsortedClass  //declares a class data type
```